# How to save email messge item generated using exchangelib library in python

Tags: python, email, save, msg, exchangelib

I have used exchangelib library to download emails from my Inbox.
The messages are eventually instance of exchangelib.items.Message.
I want to save this entire email as .msg file so that I can later attach it to some the application.
Can someone please let me know how I can do this in python ?
In Below code I want to save each element of the msgs list. Currently I am working on just one email.

'''

```
from exchangelib import Account, Configuration, Credentials, DELEGATE

def connect(server, email, username, password):
    """
    Get Exchange account cconnection with server
    """
    creds = Credentials(username=username, password=password)
    config = Configuration(server=server, credentials=creds)
    return Account(primary_smtp_address=email, autodiscover=False, config = config, access_type=DELEGATE)

def get_recent_emails(account, folder_name, count):
    """
    Retrieve most emails for a given folder
    """
    # Get the folder object
    folder = account.inbox / folder_name
    # Get emails
    return folder.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:count]

account = connect(server, email, username, password)

emails = get_recent_emails(account, 'BSS_IT', 1)
msgs = []
for msg in emails:
    msgs.append(msg)
```

'''

Comment: What is `type(msg)`?

Comment: type(msg) = <class 'exchangelib.items.Message'>

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the last 4 lines with `msgs = list(get_recent_emails(account, 'BSS_IT', 1))`

For raw source (.eml) - `msgs = [m.mime_content for m in get_recent_emails(account, 'BSS_IT', 1))]`

Comment: Thanks, will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a recognized standard for the format of `.eml` files, but at least some email clients dump the raw MIME content, which is available in exchangelib as `Message.mime_content`.

Comment: Although it is not the complete answer, I am accepting it as I can use the .eml attachment in my task. But if anyone has solution to create .msg file then please post it.